# Django dictionary in templates: Grab key from another objects attribute

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I have a dictionary called `number_devices` I'm passing to a template, the dictionary keys are the ids of a list of objects I'm also passing to the template (called `implementations`).  I'm iterating over the list of objects and then trying to use the object.id to get a value out of the dict like so:

```
    {% for implementation in implementations %}
        {{ number_devices.implementation.id }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately `number_devices.implementation` is evaluated first, then the `result.id` is evaluated obviously returning and displaying nothing.  I can't use parentheses like:

```
{{ number_devices.(implementation.id) }}
```

because I get a parse error.  How do I get around this annoyance in Django templates?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

A workaround could be using the keys from number_devices and check in the for loop if it is equal to the key provided by number_devices.

```
{% for key in number_devices.keys %}
    {% for implementation in implementations %}
        {% ifequal key implementation.id %} you got it {% endifequal %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Seems a bit ugly, but should work.